# como iterar una matriz creada con int ** m en C++?

Tags: c++, matriz, fórmulas-de-matriz

Estoy trabajando en C++ y tengo que crear una matriz de baja densidad o matriz poco poblada o sparse matrix, por lo que entiendo son lo mismo.

```
MPP::MPP(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    // INGRESE AQUÍ EL CÓDIGO DE LA FUNCIONALIDAD
    this->sizeX = sizeX;
    this->sizeY = sizeY;
    
    this->matriz = new int*[sizeX*sizeY];//Crea un arreglo de int*
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeX*sizeY; i++){//Luego anda a cada posicion del arreglo de int *
        matriz[i] = new int[4];//Y crea un nuevo arreglo de int
    }
    //Creas una matriz de 4 * (x*y)
    //D = dato
    //X = posX
    //Y = posY
    //Z = -1 o 0 
    //Z = -1 si la posicion X, Y esta ocupada
    //Z = 0 si la posicion X,Y esta desocupada
    //quedaria asi
    //[[D,X,Y, Z],
    // [D,X,Y, Z],
    // [D,X,Y, Z],
    // [D,X,Y, Z],
    // [D,X,Y, Z]]
}

void MPP::add(int dato, int posX, int posY) {
    // INGRESE AQUÍ EL CÓDIGO DE LA FUNCIONALIDAD
    std::cout<<"Quiero insertar el siguiente cuatrupla --> ("<<dato<<" ,"<<posX<<" ,"<<posY<<")"<<std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeX*sizeY; i++){
        //int * cuatrupla = matriz[i];//cuatrupla inicial.
        std::cout<<"cuatrupla datos --> ("<<matriz[i][0]<<" ,"<<matriz[i][1]<<" ,"<<matriz[i][2]<<")"<<std::endl;
        if(matriz[i][3] == 0 && matriz[i][1] == 0 && matriz[i][2] == 0){//Si la posicion tiene datos vacios && no esta ocupada.
            //inserta
            matriz[i][0] = dato;
            matriz[i][1] = posX;
            matriz[i][2] = posY;
            matriz[i][3] = -1;
            std::cout<<"Se inserto el cuatrupla quedo como :"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"cuatrupla datos --> ("<<matriz[i][0]<<" ,"<<matriz[i][1]<<" ,"<<matriz[i][2]<<")"<<std::endl;
            return;//Termina
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutar el código se me printean las direcciones de memoria, y por tanto no se harán las comparaciones correctas.

Por ejemplo los primeros 2 print al ejecutar el codigo son

**Quiero insertar el siguiente cuatrupla --> (545 ,5 ,8)**
**cuatrupla datos --> (8788560 ,0 ,8782160)**

Donde se ve que 8788560 es una direccion de memoria, igual que 8782160, entonces como puedo obtener los datos o moverme entre los datos de manera correcta :( ?

Hace un tiempo programe en C++ pero no recuerdo mucho sobre el uso de punteros y las direcciones de memoria.

Comment: De qué tipo es `matriz`? Falta la declaración de la variable

Comment: es tipo int** 
esta declarado en MPP como

int ** matriz;

Comment: bueno solucione el problema, insertando el 0 en cada posicion de la matriz

Answer (score 0):

luego de crear la matriz rellena la matriz de 0s

```
for(int i = 0; i<sizeX* sizeY; i++){
    matriz[i][0] = 0;
    matriz[i][1] = 0;
    matriz[i][2] = 0;
    matriz[i][3] = 0;
}
```

luego de eso ya puedes trabajar tranquilamente